# TrayIcon message not showing

Tags: java, notifications, system-tray

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TrayIcon t = new TrayIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("1.png"));

 t.setToolTip("Hello");

 try {
     SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(t);
 } catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

  t.displayMessage("Test", "Message", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
}
```

The problem is that the message is not shown. The tray icon is there, the program runs, but for some reason the message is not shown.

Comment: Hmm, I ran your program and it works. I can see tray icon with message ```Message```. Could you provide some more details?

Comment: I don't know what else to say... in my computer it doesn't work, it just shows the icon in the system tray, but the message is not displayed :(

Comment: What system you have, java version, etc. Maybe another guys with similar configuration will reproduce your problem. It might help.

Comment: Im on Windows 10 (64 bits) version 1703 (build 15063.483)
Java version 1.8.0_161

Comment: Guys... nevermind, im stupid, for some reason windows was not displaying notifications at all, it was in do not disturb mode...